# how can I open directory-tree in SrSpeedbar

Tags: emacs, emacs-speedbar

I use SrSpeedbar to navigate source code in Emacs, but there seems no directory tree. Could somebody give some advice of how to open directory-tree mode in SrSpeedbar?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I don't have an answer for you about SrSpeedbar. But if you are mainly looking for a way to have a navigable directory tree in a narrow window similar to speedbar's, then consider using Dired and hiding the details (i.e., all but the file names).

In recent GNU Emacs development builds (i.e., what will become Emacs 24.4) this is built-in: just use `(` to hide/show details.  (Library [Dired+](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus) makes this feature a bit more usable, by providing user options `diredp-hide-details-initially-flag` and `diredp-hide-details-propagate-flag`.)

In other Emacs versions, load library [DiredDetails](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredDetails), and then use `(`.

Hiding details this way might give you most of the functionality you seek, depending on what you need. It will also give you additional features (from Dired).